# add product barcode to the POS odoo module

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, barcode, pos

i have a small request, i have worked with Odoo before but i never had to deal with .JS files, i only used Python and XML for basic dev needs, but right now i want to make a small change in the POS module and all of it is javascript,i want to display the Product barcode in the cart under its name, im sure the product barcode is loaded from the db because i use a barcode scanner to add products to the cart, so the only problem is to display it in the cart, here is a picture to explain my problem, thanks for the great community.
[image: Check screen shot]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing useful really... i added the product name x2 and i wanted to change it to the product barcode later on but so far nothing worked... i didnt find a clear def of the class Product in the JS files... thanks for the comment

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow it is expected that you do your best to solve the problem on your own and if you get stuck ask a specific question including the code you already have.

Comment: From your requirement , you don't need js to display barcode in Cart / Orderline. You can achieve it by inheriting XML

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the File in Manifest like this,

```
"qweb": ["static/src/xml/pos.xml"],
```

Add the File **pos.xml** in this path **static/src/xml/**

You can **Extend** the Q-web Template and added Barcode like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="Orderline">
        <t t-jquery="t[t-esc='line.get_product().display_name']" t-operation="after">
            <br/><t t-esc="line.get_product().barcode"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i found it minutes before you posted this xD i just modified the original files, in pos.xml in lines 1260-1280 from
and i added <t t-esc="line.get_product().barcode"/> , thanks for the answer tho!!!!!

Comment: Try to inherit and alter base code with custom modules. Thanks.